# Executable ignoring rpath entry

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I'm trying to create an executable that uses a set of locally installed dynamic libraries, however when I try to run the program I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libSDL2-2.0.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Volumes/OSXData/Users/danielrs/Development/Projects/Test/build/./ClearScreen
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Executinng the command `otool -L ClearScreen` gives:

```
ClearScreen:
    /Volumes/OSXData/Users/danielrs/Development/Projects/Test/build/DwarfEngine/libDwarf.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    libSDL2-2.0.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 0.2.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 21.0.0)
    /Volumes/OSXData/Users/danielrs/Development/Projects/Test/DwarfEngine/dependencies/../3rdParty/Darwin/lib/libglfw.3.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.8.0)
    /Volumes/OSXData/Users/danielrs/Development/Projects/Test/DwarfEngine/dependencies/../3rdParty/Darwin//libassimp.3.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.1.1)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

All this libraries but SDL and Assimp are located were expected. Since I build and install them using CMake's ExternalProject_Add, the install_name of the .dylib is changed during install phase. After reading A LOT, I found that the executable looks for its libs in the paths specified in DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH before trying the location specified by install name. So I set that to point to the folder were my libraries are installed:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Volumes/OSXData/Users/danielrs/Development/Projects/Test/DwarfEngine/3rdParty/Darwin/lib
```

And everything works! However, the project will create a lot of executables and I wanted them to know were to look for the libraries instead of exporting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH manually, the best solution is to set a rpath in the executable. I did the following:

```
# Unset this so they don't override the rpath
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
install_name_tool -add_rpath /Volumes/OSXData/Users/danielrs/Development/Projects/Test/DwarfEngine/3rdParty/Darwin/lib ClearScreen
```

**But it won't work**. I thought that dyld looked in the rpath before trying install names in the .dylib? Here's the output of `otool -l ClearScreen` after adding the rpath (the LC_RPATH is located at the end):

```
ClearScreen:
Load command 0
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __PAGEZERO
   vmaddr 0x0000000000000000
   vmsize 0x0000000100000000
  fileoff 0
 filesize 0
  maxprot 0x00000000
 initprot 0x00000000
   nsects 0
    flags 0x0
Load command 1
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 712
  segname __TEXT
   vmaddr 0x0000000100000000
   vmsize 0x0000000000004000
  fileoff 0
 filesize 16384
  maxprot 0x00000007
 initprot 0x00000005
   nsects 8
    flags 0x0
Section
  sectname __text
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100003ab0
      size 0x0000000000000369
    offset 15024
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x80000400
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __stubs
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100003e1a
      size 0x000000000000005a
    offset 15898
     align 2^1 (2)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x80000408
 reserved1 0 (index into indirect symbol table)
 reserved2 6 (size of stubs)
Section
  sectname __stub_helper
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100003e74
      size 0x0000000000000092
    offset 15988
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x80000400
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __const
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100003f08
      size 0x000000000000000d
    offset 16136
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __gcc_except_tab
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100003f18
      size 0x000000000000002c
    offset 16152
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __cstring
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100003f44
      size 0x0000000000000019
    offset 16196
     align 2^0 (1)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000002
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __unwind_info
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100003f60
      size 0x0000000000000060
    offset 16224
     align 2^2 (4)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __eh_frame
   segname __TEXT
      addr 0x0000000100003fc0
      size 0x0000000000000038
    offset 16320
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Load command 2
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 392
  segname __DATA
   vmaddr 0x0000000100004000
   vmsize 0x0000000000001000
  fileoff 16384
 filesize 4096
  maxprot 0x00000007
 initprot 0x00000003
   nsects 4
    flags 0x0
Section
  sectname __nl_symbol_ptr
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100004000
      size 0x0000000000000010
    offset 16384
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000006
 reserved1 15 (index into indirect symbol table)
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __got
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100004010
      size 0x0000000000000008
    offset 16400
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000006
 reserved1 17 (index into indirect symbol table)
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __la_symbol_ptr
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100004018
      size 0x0000000000000078
    offset 16408
     align 2^3 (8)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000007
 reserved1 18 (index into indirect symbol table)
 reserved2 0
Section
  sectname __const
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100004090
      size 0x0000000000000058
    offset 16528
     align 2^4 (16)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0
Load command 3
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __LINKEDIT
   vmaddr 0x0000000100005000
   vmsize 0x0000000000001000
  fileoff 20480
 filesize 2628
  maxprot 0x00000007
 initprot 0x00000001
   nsects 0
    flags 0x0
Load command 4
            cmd LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY
        cmdsize 48
     rebase_off 20480
    rebase_size 16
       bind_off 20496
      bind_size 216
  weak_bind_off 20712
 weak_bind_size 56
  lazy_bind_off 20768
 lazy_bind_size 400
     export_off 21168
    export_size 208
Load command 5
     cmd LC_SYMTAB
 cmdsize 24
  symoff 21816
   nsyms 30
  stroff 22428
 strsize 680
Load command 6
            cmd LC_DYSYMTAB
        cmdsize 80
      ilocalsym 0
      nlocalsym 3
     iextdefsym 3
     nextdefsym 10
      iundefsym 13
      nundefsym 17
         tocoff 0
           ntoc 0
      modtaboff 0
        nmodtab 0
   extrefsymoff 0
    nextrefsyms 0
 indirectsymoff 22296
  nindirectsyms 33
      extreloff 0
        nextrel 0
      locreloff 0
        nlocrel 0
Load command 7
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLINKER
      cmdsize 32
         name /usr/lib/dyld (offset 12)
Load command 8
     cmd LC_UUID
 cmdsize 24
    uuid 967CAC7D-945E-3767-89AD-7BF4D62D0903
Load command 9
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.10
      sdk 10.10
Load command 10
      cmd LC_SOURCE_VERSION
  cmdsize 16
  version 0.0
Load command 11
       cmd LC_MAIN
   cmdsize 24
  entryoff 15392
 stacksize 0
Load command 12
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 120
         name /Volumes/OSXData/Users/danielrs/Development/Projects/Test/build/DwarfEngine/libDwarf.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 0.0.0
Load command 13
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 80
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 14
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 15
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name libSDL2-2.0.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 0.2.1
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 16
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 21.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 17
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 152
         name /Volumes/OSXData/Users/danielrs/Development/Projects/Test/DwarfEngine/dependencies/../3rdParty/Darwin/lib/libglfw.3.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 3.1.0
compatibility version 3.0.0
Load command 18
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 275.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 19
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 96
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 1.8.0
compatibility version 1.2.0
Load command 20
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 152
         name /Volumes/OSXData/Users/danielrs/Development/Projects/Test/DwarfEngine/dependencies/../3rdParty/Darwin//libassimp.3.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 3.1.1
compatibility version 3.0.0
Load command 21
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 120.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 22
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 20:00:02 1969
      current version 1213.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 23
      cmd LC_FUNCTION_STARTS
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 21376
 datasize 16
Load command 24
      cmd LC_DATA_IN_CODE
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 21392
 datasize 0
Load command 25
      cmd LC_DYLIB_CODE_SIGN_DRS
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 21392
 datasize 424
Load command 26
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 104
         path /Volumes/OSXData/Users/danielrs/Development/Projects/Test/DwarfEngine/3rdParty/Darwin/lib (offset 12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting `LC_RPATH` with `-add-rpath` you must still add `@rpath` variable to the relocated library path. The variable will be substituted with added rpath value.

```
install_name_tool -change libSDL2-2.0.1.dylib @rpath/libSDL2-2.0.1.dylib ClearScreen
```

For the `-change` option you give two parameters: `old_path` and `new_path`. `old_path` must be exactly what you get from `otool -L`.

You will find some useful info in [cmake wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling).

Comment: It works, thank you! Sadly, there's no easy way to do this change automatically right? Using CMake, I tried to pass the argument `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH='@rpath/lib'` to CMAKE_ARGS in ExternalProject_Add when adding SDL

Comment: You could ask new question on how to set rpath correctly using cmake. When the paths are broken as they are now you could only write a script to fix it automatically. [This script](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/subversion/subversion-52/rpath_subversion.sh) could be an inspiration to you.

Comment: That script is perfect! Keep it up!